# apply custom function to a particular column rowise by group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, apply

I had a function to find the max value until current row number.

```
dt<- setDT(copy(mtcars),keep.rownames = TRUE)

apply(as.matrix(dt$rn), 1, function(x) {
 index = as.numeric(ifelse(match(x, dt$rn) == 1, 2, match(x, dt$rn)))
 max(dt[1:index-1,"mpg",with = FALSE])
 })
   # [1] 21.0 21.0 21.0 22.8 22.8 22.8 22.8 22.8 24.4 24.4 24.4 24.4 24.4 24.4 24.4 24.4 24.4 24.4 32.4 32.4 33.9 33.9 33.9 33.9 33.9 33.9 33.9 33.9 33.9 33.9 33.9
   # [32] 33.9
```

However, I would like to repeat the same based on a particular group say 'gear'. How would I modify the code. I feel it has to do with something like this.

```
dt[,max:=lapply(.SD,function(x){
         index = as.numeric(ifelse(match(x,dt$rn) == 1, 2, match(x, dt$rn)))
      return(max(dt[1:index-1,"mpg",with = FALSE]))
      }),by = gear,.SDcols = "rn"]
```

I feel I may be missing something..

Comment: Your function could be replaced by just `cummax(dt$mpg)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg op is missing the parens in `1:index-1`, right? so fixing that gives me a difference in one value

Comment: @rawr yes, I think you are right

Comment: Would `dt$mpg` have the values within the group?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Also it's not just the maximum value within the group. but upto the current row number in that group hence the 1:index-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a data.table solution

```
dt[, currMax := cummax(shift(mpg, fill = -Inf)), by = gear], 
head(dt)
#                      rn  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb currMax
# 1:         Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    -Inf
# 2:     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    21.0
# 3:        Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    21.0
# 4:    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1    -Inf
# 5: Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2    21.4
# 6:           Valiant 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1    21.4
```

Thanks @DavidArenburg for the edit.

Comment: No, that doesn't look like a `data.table` solution rather a copy/paste from comments/other answer. `data.table` doesn't have the `lag` function. One possible solution could be `dt[, currMax := cummax(shift(mpg, fill = -Inf)), by = gear]`, for instance

Answer (score 1):

Not sure in data.table, but relatively straightforward in `dplyr`. Set `group_by` then `mutate` which operates within the group.

```
res <-
  mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  mutate(currMax = cummax(mpg))
```

Here is a subset of the result, achieved with:

```
res %>%
  select(gear, mpg, currMax) %>%
  slice(1:3)
```

To limit the result to relevant columns and the first three rows from each group.

```
   gear   mpg currMax
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     3  21.4    21.4
2     3  18.7    21.4
3     3  18.1    21.4
4     4  21.0    21.0
5     4  21.0    21.0
6     4  22.8    22.8
7     5  26.0    26.0
8     5  30.4    30.4
9     5  15.8    30.4
```

If you want the maximum value for every row up to, but not including, the current row, you will need to do a bit more manipulating. Specifically, `cummax` does not have built in handling of `NA` and by definition your first value needs to be `NA`. So, I wrote a small function that temporarily changes `NA` to negative infinity, then sets those entries to `NA` before returning (this will be a problem if and only if your data actually *has* `-Inf` values, and even then only if they are first in the data). Then, I use that function as the trailing max:

```
my_cummax <- function(x){
  x <- ifelse(is.na(x), -Inf, x)
  out <- cummax(x)
  out[out == -Inf] <- NA
  return(out)
}

mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  mutate(currMax = cummax(mpg)
         , trailMax = my_cummax(lag(mpg)))
```

A limited slice of the return, similar to above, shows:

```
   gear   mpg currMax trailMax
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1     3  21.4    21.4       NA
2     3  18.7    21.4     21.4
3     3  18.1    21.4     21.4
4     4  21.0    21.0       NA
5     4  21.0    21.0     21.0
6     4  22.8    22.8     21.0
7     5  26.0    26.0       NA
8     5  30.4    30.4     26.0
9     5  15.8    30.4     30.4
```

Comment: `dt[, .(mpg, currMax = cummax(mpg)), by = gear]`? It's just the usual by group operation

Comment: @MarkPeterson I didn't check the answer before making the edit. Also, It's not just the maximum value within the group. but up to the current row number ore index in that group hence the 1:index-1

Comment: @DavidArenburg Sure could be -- I was not offering a data.table solution because it is not something I use. If that will work, feel free to post as an alternative answer.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Do you reckon there is a dplyr modification to account for the row number as well.

Comment: @theArun -- What is the desired output? I may have misunderstood; I thought you were just looking for a running max. I am not sure what you intend to get with the `index-1` portion.

Comment: Are you looking for the maximum value in any row of that group up to (and including) the current row? Because that is what I have output here. If you want it to not include the current, I can modify for that. If it is something different, you will have to give me a more thorough explanation.

Comment: I'm looking for the maximum value of all predecessor values up to the current row (not including) within a group.

Comment: Solid point @Frank, thank you. I updated accordingly. I wanted to make sure that I could show a reasonable set of entries from each group, but you are right that my previous approach could easily have led to confusion.